# HighCharts : Tooltips exist but line is not drawn in the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I met with a problem on HighCharts.

I had to gather data from a xml content with ajax in order to draw it in a HighCharts chart.

I get my datas. I can see my points when I move my mouse over it but my chart is not displaying anything.

A picture to see the problem :
[mouse over the third point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjYZe.png)

And some parts from my code if it can help :

```
var myData=[];

function makeChart() {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function () {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2',
            type: 'spline',
            borderColor: '#DC143C',
            borderRadius: 20,
            borderWidth: 2,
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories :[0,1,2,3,4,5]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Values'
            },
        },
        series: [{
                color: '#FF00FF',
                name: '',
                data: myData
            }]
    });
});
}


$(function (){

$(document).ready(function ping(){

    ChartDeOuf();
    makeChart();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/SASI/runSimulation',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(result){
            var i = 0;

            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(result);
            var chart = $('#container2').highcharts();
            $result = $(xmlDoc);

            $(result).find('measure').each(function(){
                var $value = $(this);
                var attr = $value.attr("meanValue");

                myData[i]=attr;

                var html = '<p> '+myData[i]+'</p>';
                chart.series[0].addPoint({y: myData[i]},false);

                chart.redraw();
                $('body').append($(html));
                i++;


            })

        },
        error: function(result){
            alert('timeout/error');
        }
    });
});

});
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, that line saved everything :

```
myData[i]=parseFloat(attr);
```